# Build WinObjC app on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, winobjc

Currently I am using Ubuntu linux and I want to create a WinObjC app on Linux plateform. Is there any way to create WinObj apps on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disapoint you, but unfortunately there is not. WinObjC is intended to bring iOS apps to Windows 10. Basically it just enables you to write Windows 10 apps in Objective-C but you still need a Windows 10 machine to compile it.

A **Windows 10** device and **Visual Studio** **are mandatory at the moment**, to create WinObjC apps.